# Blocking direct access to an URL (not a file)

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7, plesk

A drupal site is pushing International traffic over quota on my (Plesk 10.4) server, and it looks as though much of that of that (~250,000 visits/month) is direct access to the URL /user/register. We are already using the botcha module to filter out spambot registrations, but that approach is resulting in two full pages being served to each bot. And while Drupal

I'm thinking that a .htaccess rule which returns a 403 response to that URL unless the referer is from the site might be the way to go, but my .htaccess-fu is not strong, and I can only find examples for blocking hot-linking of images.

What do I need to add and where?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: You have to placed strings from Jon Lin answer to ".htaccess" file in domain web root, not in vhost.conf.

Comment: Yes, the directory I was targeting isn't an actual physical directory (in which case vhost.conf should have worked). I ended up with the code in .htaccess just ahead of the code which directed all other virtual paths to index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be checking against the HTTP referer. It's not a guarantee way to block incoming traffic linked from a site other than yours, since the field can be easily forged. But you can try adding this to the htaccess file (above any rules that are already there):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?your-domain\com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^user/register - [L,F]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon, I put that into a vhost.conf file for the domain and went through the rigmarole Plesk forces on us to update. Nothing has broken, but I seem to still be able to access the page directly. does [link](http://www.permaculture.org.nz/user/register) still work for you?

Comment: Clicking the link I just posted results in a 200 response with stackoverflow.com as the referer :-(